# How to define a function which takes another function as input in Module

Tags: functions, evaluation, pattern-matching

Let $f$ be a function of $n$. I would like to define a function $A$ with module which takes $f[n]$ as input. So for example:

```
f[n_]:=f[n]=(n^2+1)/n;
A[f[n]_]:=A[f[n]]=Module[{d},
d[n_]=d[n]=Numerator[f[n-1]];
Return[d[n]]
]
```

My code above does not work. I want `f[n]` still be a function of `n` inside the module but it seems I did it wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of a function defined with a pattern like `f[n_]`, you can try `f = Function[n, (n^2 + 1)/n]`. Then pass both `f` and `n` to `A`: `A[f_Function, n_] := ...`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer. I think I cannot do that because actually f is another output from another function. But thanks for the answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
ClearAll[A]
Attributes@A = HoldAll;
A[f[n_]] := A[f[n]] = Module[{d}, d = Numerator@f[n - 1]]
```

I've removed the redundant `Return`. `Module` is also irrelevant here actually. Anyway, I suppose you need `Module` in your real problem so don't take it away.

Or you need `f` to be arbitrary, too? Then:

```
ClearAll[A]
Attributes@A = HoldAll;
A[f_[n_]] := A[f[n]] = Module[{d}, d = Numerator@f[n - 1]]

f[n_] := f[n] = (n^2 + 1)/n;
g[n_] := g[n] = (n^2 + 2)/n;

A[g[3]]
(* 3 *)
A[f[3]]
(* 5 *)

A // DownValues
(* {HoldPattern[A[f[3]]] :> 5, HoldPattern[A[g[3]]] :> 3, 
    HoldPattern[A[f_[n_]]] :> (A[f[n]] = Module[{d}, d = Numerator[f[n - 1]]])} *)
```

Comment: +1 for the nice examples, but if interpretation is correct, and I think it is, this should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, I believe it's a duplicate, too, but posts about functions are really hard to search 囧. Hope someone can find the duplicate post.

Comment: Oh. This works! But when I removed Attributes@A = HoldAll; it did not work. What is that for?

Comment: Oh when I make $d$ a function in $n$ too, it doeas not work.
A[f_[n_]] := A[f[n]] = Module[{d}, d[n_]:=d[n] = Numerator@f[n - 1]] doesn't work.

Sorry, I do not know how to format a code in a comment.

Comment: @ChenMLing To understand the meaning of `Attributes@A = HoldAll;`, just check the document of [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) and [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), you may also feel [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/1871) interesting. As to the `d[n]` part, I don't quite understand what you mean. What output are you expecting?

Comment: @xzczd I am expecting the output will be a function of n as well, so it will Return[d[n]]. I have edited my question :)

Comment: @ChenMLing Are you expecting to create a function `d[n]` that can be used outside e.g. something like `A[f[n]]; d[3] (*output: 5*)`? Then you should not localize `d` with `Module`. Or you just want a expression rather than function? Then you don't need to define function inside the `Module`. BTW formatting code in comment is the same as formatting in post.

Comment: @xzczd, my real code takes function of n as input and gives function of n as output. What I have learnt is to use Module to write big function, and return what we are expected. I don't know how to do it without Module.

Comment: @ChenMLing `Module` is a function for localization i.e. isolating the possible influence from outside. Writing big function does often require using `Module` etc. but it doesn't mean you can use it blindly. Check  documentation of [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) for more details. To be blunter: don't use `Module` if you don't understand what you're getting from it. In your case what you need is simply: `d[n_] := d[n] = Numerator@f[n - 1]`.

Comment: @xzczd. OK, understand :) Thank you very much x :)